# How to modify CSS styles on output from custom function for WooCommerce shop page hook

Tags: hook-woocommerce

For our WooCommerce shop and archive pages, our developer set up the ability to output custom values beneath the product title using the "woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title" hook and a PHP function.

The output looks great on desktop, but the font-size and line-height is too large on mobile. See images below.

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPXCw.jpg)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIgND.jpg)

I would like to know how to assign a custom class to this PHP output, so that I can modify the font size and line high (for mobile only) using css. See PHP code below which generates the output.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop', 5 );
 
function bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop() {

   echo do_shortcode("[wpv-post-link item='@artist-product.parent']");
   echo "<br>";     
   echo do_shortcode("[product_dimensions]");
   echo "<br>"; 
   echo do_shortcode("[stock_status]");

}
```

Note that the product title (first line beneath the product image in the pictures linked above) and the product price (last line beneath the product image in the pictures linked above) are not part of the custom output via the code above, these are standard WooCommerce elements. I know how to modify the font-size and line-height for these separately.

Thanks!

I have looked at a lot of forums with similar questions and tried to follow their instructions to  assign a new HTML class to the PHP code above, but I have minimal coding experience and am obviously doing something wrong.